# Is there a method in Pytorch to count the number of unique values in a way that can be back propagated?

Tags: pytorch, counting, backpropagation

Given the following tensor (which is the result of a network [note the grad_fn]):

```
tensor([121., 241., 125.,   1., 108., 238., 125., 121.,  13., 117., 121., 229.,
        161.,  13.,   0., 202., 161., 121., 121.,   0., 121., 121., 242., 125.],
       grad_fn=<MvBackward>)
```

Which we will define as:

```py
xx = torch.tensor([121., 241., 125.,   1., 108., 238., 125., 121.,  13., 117., 121., 229.,
        161.,  13.,   0., 202., 161., 121., 121.,   0., 121., 121., 242., 125.]).requires_grad_(True)
```

I would like to define an operation which counts the number of occurrences of each value in such a way that the operation will output the following tensor:

```
tensor([2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 1, 1])
```

i.e. there are 2 zeros, 1 one, 2 thirteens, etc... the total number of possible values is set upstream, but in this example is 243

So far I have tried the following approaches, which successfully produce the desired tensor, but do not do so in a way that allows computing gradients back through the network:

#### Attempt 1

```py
tt = []
for i in range(243):
    tt.append((xx == i).unsqueeze(0))
torch.cat(tt,dim=0).sum(dim=1)
```

#### Attempt 2

```py
tvtensor = torch.tensor([i for i in range(243)]).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,xx.shape[0]).float().requires_grad_(True)
(xx==tvtensor).sum(dim=1)
```

EDIT: Added Attempt

#### Attempt 3

-- Didn't really expect this to back prop, but figured I would give it a try anyway

```py
ll = torch.zeros((1,243))
for x in xx:
    ll[0,x.long()] += 1
```

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: As requested the end goal of this is the following:

I am using a technique for calculating structural similarity between two time sequences. One is real and the other is generated. The technique is outlined in this paper (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-02279-1_33) where a time series is converted to a sequence of code words and the distribution of code words (similar to the way that Bag of Words is used in NLP) is used to represent the time series. Two series are considered similar when the two signal distributions are similar. This is what the counting statistics tensor is for.

What is desired is to be able to construct a loss function which consumes this tensor and measures the distance between the real and generated signal (euclidian norm on the time domain data directly does not work well and this approach claimed better results), so that it can update the generator appropriately.

Answer (score 8):

I would do it with `unique` method (only to count occurrences):

[image]

if you want to count the occurrences, you have to add the parameter `return_counts=True`

[image]

I did it in the version 1.3.1

[image]

This is the fast way to count occurrences, however is a non-differentiable operation, therefore, this method is not recommendable (anyway I have described the way to count ocurrences). To perform what you want, I think you should turn the input into a distribution by means of a differentiable function (softmax is the most used) and then, use some way to measure the distance between distributions (output and target) like cross-entropy, KL (kullback-liebler), JS or wasserstein.

Comment: unique is non-differentiable operation, cannot be back propagated

Comment: @FiRas your right, It may be an incomplete answer. I fix it

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to do that as `unique` is simply non-differentiable operation.

Furthermore, only `floating` point tensors can have gradient as it's defined only for real numbers domain, not for integers.

Still, there might be another, differentiable way to do what you want to achieve, but that's a different question.

Comment: Ok so this explains why the attempts don't work as they use comparison operators which as they are producing integers, they would not have a grad_fn? Is there a differentiable way that you can think of that might produce an equivalent result?

Comment: It depends on what your end goal is (I suppose it's not taking unique values). As described above, one could combine differentiable functions in order to get approximation of what you are after. Usually though, it's not necessary and you might be able to cricumvent out of non-differentiability somehow. Please describe your end goal, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The "uniquify" operation is non-differentiable, but there might be ways to remedy this, for instance, by writing a custom operator, or by a clever combination of differentiable operators.

However, you need to ask yourself this question: what do you expect the gradient of such operation to be? Or, on a higher level, what are you trying to achieve with this operation?

Comment: The output is part of a generative model, and the tensor that I have shown above is the result of an operation which is a codified version of a generated signal. The counting statistics represent the number of occurrences of different codes within the generated signal and are in this framework representative of the quality of the signal. Therefore the gradients I am looking for would be with respect to changes in the number of occurrences of each value in the tensor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use case, but it doesn't seem like something with well-defined gradients. What you're describing is just differences, i.e. derivatives in the discrete case, and I don't think that's something optimizable by the kind of techniques offered by traditional DL libraries.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're trying to constraint the model to generate a certain number of specific signals. In that case, you might want to explore some controlled generation models. I'm no expert in these, but a general idea could be to attach a classifier to the output, and ask it to classify the number of occurrences for a specific signal, and then add a penalty term based on the prediction.