# Attaching a loss to PyTorch's computational graph

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a model and inputs:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import grad
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class net_x(nn.Module): 
        def __init__(self):
            super(net_x, self).__init__()
            self.fc1=nn.Linear(1, 1) 
            self.out=nn.Linear(1, 1) 

        def forward(self, x):
            x=self.fc1(x)
            x=self.out(x)
            return x

nx = net_x()
#inputs
t = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.2], requires_grad = True) #input vector
t = torch.reshape(t, (3,1)) #reshape for batch
```

I'm trying to create a custom loss based on 2 lists (will make more sense in a minute):

```
pred_lst = []
goal_lst = list(range(10))
```

My training loop is:

```
for epoch in range(10):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    y = nx(t)
    if torch.sum(y) > 5:
        lst.append(epoch) 
    else:
        pass
    loss = len(set(pred_lst).symmetric_difference(set(goal_lst)))
    loss = torch.tensor(float(loss), requires_grad = True)
    print('loss: ', loss)
    loss.backward()

print('\nafter training')
for p in nx.parameters():
    print(p)
```

Essentially in this example, if the model's output is `>5`, `pred_lst` saves the epoch number. At the end, the loss is simply the total number of epochs that the epoch number wasn't saved.

This doesn't work as from my understanding the loss is not connected to the computational graph and hence the parameters are not being updated:

```
>>>
before training
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.7613]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.3810], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.9269]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.8938], requires_grad=True)

loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)
loss:  tensor(10., requires_grad=True)

after training
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.7613]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.3810], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.9269]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.8938], requires_grad=True)
```

How can I "attach"/"connect" this loss to the computational graph nevertheless?

Comment: How do you plan to backprop from your operation, which appears to be non-differentiable? Also relevant: [Is there a method in Pytorch to count the number of unique values in a way that can be back propagated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58598773/5987698)

Comment: That's part of my question. I know the value of the loss, and was hoping that there's a way to attach it to the end point of the computational graph. From there just backprop backwards. That link was pretty useful though. I might be able to change the way I'm finding the difference between the list like they suggested, but that's a different question.